# Тип предложений?

Tags: синтаксис

Пожалуйста, определите типы следующих предложений (тем самым поможете мне более качественно написать диплом): 
1.Один, как тень. 2.Девушка Online. 3.Ctrl+Alt+Del. 4.1Q84. 5.140 6.1+1. 7.90210.

Comment: Допускаете, что это предложения?

Comment: понятия не имею, что есть что. 
не поможете?

Comment: Начните делать, — и помощь придёт. Только, скорее всего, не с этой стороны.

Comment: я уже заканчиваю делать. Только эти 8 случаев не дают покоя.

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, пожалуйста, отметьте его [как принятый](/help/accepted-answer) (галочка рядом с ответом).

Answer (score 1):

1.Один, как тень. - или парцеллированная конструкция, или диалогически неполное предложение.

2.Девушка Online. - Девушка в сети. - полное двусоставное нераспространённое предложение.

3, 4, 5, 6 - скорее всего, не являются предложениями. Это обозначения. Полной информации они не дают. Ну вот как название стихотворения или сочинения. После них даже точки не ставят, потому что предложениями они не являются, они только обозначили тему информации, а самой информации нет: тема есть, ремы нет.

Comment: спасибо, Людмила!

Comment: Ctrl+Alt+Del — команда, «горячие клавиши».

Comment: Знаю, но это виртуальная команда, а в письменной речи это только названия клавиш.

Comment: *Девушка в сети* – точно ли двусоставное? Номинативное же. По крайней мере, можно считать номинативным.

Comment: Не думаю, что "в сети" - качество девушки( как "девушка в косынке"), явно же, что это информация о том, что девушка доступна для общения, это рема,  сказуемое. Тихий день - номинативное, а День тихий - двусоставное.